# show multi column on hover in bootstrap using custom css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" style="width:100%">
            <div class="container"> 
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
                    <li ><a id="firstid" href="#">FOR HIM</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" >FOR HER</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">FOR KIDS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PERSONALIZED</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BIRTHDAYS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NOVELTY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">EXPERIENCES</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">OCCASIONS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NEW</a></li>

                </ul>

                <ul id="multicol-menu" class="nav pull-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">MultiCol Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                    <div class="row" style="width: 400px;">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                            <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled col-md-4">
                            <li><a href="#">a</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">b</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
            </div>

CSS
#multicol-menu{
            display: none;
        }
        #firstid:hover #multicol-menu{
            display: block;

        }
```

I have written above code having a navigation bar now i want to show 3 columns list item on hover.I have tried different things but could't get the result.it would be very nice it anyone provide same as in the image. i have written custom css too but its not working.My intention is to show like in the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nthnl.png

Comment: you have to do it with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Well, try the following CSS:

```
div.row {
  width: 400px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}

ul.list-unstyled {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
}

#multicol-menu li.dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: bro its working as dropdown when we click but i want hover. as in the image.https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nthnl.png